# ¿Cómo hago para poder preguntar?

Tags: discusión, soporte, moderadores, bloqueo-de-publicación

Hace un tiempo me impidieron preguntar.

La verdad todavía no entendí por qué, pero leí que hay que hacer respuestas para que me saquen el bloqueo, así que empecé a responder y me agregaron más puntos negativos, con justificaciones erradas a mi gusto, ya que mi forma de responder la vi, y veo siempre, entendí que esa puntuación negativa era solo el uso de poder de un usuario sobre otro, o el querer decir "yo estoy atento a las malas respuestas". Ahora no encuentro esas respuestas y la discusión con este usuario, pero ¿hay alguien que sea justo y arbitre estos temas y que no cualquier persona te pueda puntuar negativo?

Necesito preguntar y no puedo.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] te invito a hacer el [tour] asi conoces un poco mas de como funcionamos,el solo leerlo podras tener algunas medallas

Comment: tienes muchas preguntas abiertas, y al parecer ninguna te funciono?, si es asi, porque no agregastes una respuesta y la aceptas tu mismo, recuerdas que existen mas usuarios que pueden tener el mismo problema

Comment: Sería bueno traducir el artículo [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/209901)

Comment: @fedorqui está explicado en el centro de ayuda: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans

Comment: Lucho no olvides aceptar las respuesta que te ayudo a tus preguntas, y si encontrastes la solucion respondete y aceptala, para esto ultimo tienes que esperar un dia

Comment: Hola, realmente lo de aceptar las respuestas nunca le di imortancia, y eso fue el error, ahora estuve viendo, y voy a seguir, aceptando respuestas y puntuando.[
Por otro lado @fedorqui me encantaria saber ingles al nivel de poder traducir un texto entero, quizá sea peor si lo intento, ;)
Igualmente no creo q aceptando las respuestas pueda preguntar, no se especifica en ningún lado eso.
En fin gracias a todos por responder, voy a seguir sus concejos y ver si en un tiempo se revierte la situación.Muchas gracias.

Comment: Fijate que con eso poquito que hiciste, el baneo ya se te levanto. Sin embargo, tene en cuenta que estas en la cuerda floja. Tus posteos deben ser de calidad, tanto preguntando como contestando. Si no, el baneo va a volver. Es importante que leas todo lo que te pasamos, y que tengas en cuenta que tus preguntas sean claras.

Comment: SI!! Buenisimo, @gbianchi, ok, gracias.

Comment: Si tenes mas dudas, tenes suficiente reputación para entrar al [chat]

Comment: @Pikoh anda, no me había fijado. Gracias. Igualmente, veo que la publicación de Meta.SE tiene más indicaciones.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Qué puedo hacer cuando recibo el comentario "Ya no aceptamos preguntas/respuestas de esta cuenta"?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4329/qu%c3%a9-puedo-hacer-cuando-recibo-el-comentario-ya-no-aceptamos-preguntas-respuest)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Mirando tu cuenta, si, estas bloqueado para pregunta. Esto se debe a que tenes muchas preguntas con 0 votos, ninguna pregunta con una respuesta aceptada (de 37 preguntas, en ninguna te contestaron algo que respondiera tu pregunta?) y un monton de respuestas tambien con cero votos, respuestas duplicadas a la misma pregunta, y muchos otros motivos por los cuales el sistema te bloquea automaticamente.

Nadie tiene algo contra vos, y si asi fuera podes conectarte con el equipo de moderación para que analicen el caso y puedan ver si algo esta mal. Pero si te puedo decir, que tu cuenta tiene varias cosas muy raras.

Sos usuario desde hace casi 3 años, y no sabes como funciona el sitio todavia. No leiste ni siquiera el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Esto lo sabemos, porque al leerlo se te otorga una medalla que no tenes.

Aparte de eso, leiste alguna vez [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) o [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)?

Tu cuenta fue bloqueada automaticamente por el sistema, porque considera que no haces aportes productivos al sitio. La unica forma de levantar esta restriccion es que empieces a hacer aportes al sitio que sirvan. Borrar tus preguntas (tenes muchas preguntas y respuestas borradas) no es uno de ellos. Debes actualizar tus preguntas, responder las que tienen respuesta, aceptar las respuestas que solucionaron tus problemas (tuyas o de otros) y ayudar con el sitio (editando cuando veas errores y tratando de obtener reputación haciendo cosas productivas en el mismo).

Lo que si podes hacer, es entrar al [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) donde encontraras gente que te ayudara a mejorar los aspectos de tu cuenta para que puedas volver a preguntar, y tambien para que no te vuelva a pasar lo mismo.

Revisa tu cuenta. Trabaja sobre ella. El sistema permite ciertos desvios, pero cuando bloquea por si mismo, nadie puede levantarte dicho bloqueo, solo tu mismo.