# ¿Qué puedo hacer cuando recibo el comentario "Ya no aceptamos preguntas/respuestas de esta cuenta"?

Tags: soporte, propuesta-de-faq, bloqueo-de-publicación

> <sub>Esta es una traducción de [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/209901)</sub>

Cuando vas a preguntar, puede que veas el mensaje:

> Lo sentimos, ya no aceptamos más preguntas de esta cuenta. Consulta el [Centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) para obtener más información.

O, al intentar contestar:

> Lo sentimos, ya no aceptamos más respuestas de esta cuenta. Consulta el [Centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans) para obtener más información.

- ¿Por qué recibo este mensaje?
- ¿Se tienen también en cuenta las publicaciones borradas?
- ¿Es el bloqueo de preguntar o de responder la misma cosa que una suspensión?
- ¿Cómo evito que se me bloquee para preguntar o responder?
- ¿Cuánto tiempo tengo que esperar para volver a publicar? ¿Qué puedo hacer para dejar de estar bloqueado? ¿Cómo puedo reactivar mi cuenta?
- ¿Puedo simplemente crear una nueva cuenta?
- ¡Lo preguntaré en otro sitio y desde allí migrarán la pregunta a este sitio!
- ¿Aplica el bloqueo también a Meta?
- ¿Por qué se me bloquea de preguntar / responder si mi cuenta tiene un buen rendimiento?

> El [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) contiene más información sobre [bloqueos de preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) y [bloqueos de responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans).

Answer (score 2):

Traducción de https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/209901, código fuente en https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/852f028a-a236-4ae3-823a-7a54cddd197b/view-source. Traducción colaborativa en marcha

### ¿Por qué recibo este mensaje?

Como se indica en el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), Stack Exchange es una red de *sitios de preguntas y respuestas*, no unos foros de ayuda. Esto implica que se espera que todas las publicaciones tengan algún valor para los futuros visitantes. Para reforzar este punto y para prevenir que los [vampiros de la ayuda](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) espanten a la gente que responde, las preguntas y respuestas de baja calidad son bloqueadas. Esto incluye publicaciones de:

- usuarios que no se molestan en formar frases.
- usuarios que no hacen la más mínima investigación por sí mismos.
- usuarios que apenas explican qué es lo que quieren hacer.

Existe un [filtro automático](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system/60294#60294) que bloquea preguntas y/o respuestas de direcciones IP o cuentas con un historial de publicaciones *extremadamente* malas.

Para evitar que se evite este filtro, sus reglas exactas son secretas, pero está basado parcialmente en los votos negativos emitidos por otros miembros de las comunidades. Si otros miembros del sitio dan a tus publicaciones una puntuación baja de forma sistemática, deberías intentar identificar la/s razón/es de ello.

Cuando has publicado demasiadas preguntas o respuestas mal recibidas, se te bloqueará la publicación de nuevas preguntas o respuestas. Además, verás este mensaje de error.

### ¿Se tienen también en cuenta las publicaciones borradas?

If a post was poorly-received (downvoted or closed), that will continue to count against your account **even if the post is deleted!** Whenever possible, try to fix posts instead of deleting them.

Additionally, deletion itself counts against questions if [less than 30 days old when deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91956/i-apparently-got-question-banned-for-deleting-some-of-my-old-zero-upvoted-quest/97720#97720) if others have invested time into answering or moderating the question.

Finally, [deleted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105116/sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-answers-from-this-account/105119#105119) always count towards an automatic answer-ban on new accounts - so make sure that you've posted a few well-received answers to counter those you've removed.

It's not a problem to have deleted posts. But if a large percentage of your posts are deleted by yourself or the community, then apparently they are not suitable for the site. Posting them consumes time from users who read them, edit them, or [respond to them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented/74471#74471). Therefore deleted posts [have](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86982/should-i-avoid-deleting-my-questions/87029#87029) an effect on the filter, among many other factors.

Beware that an account might very well have many deleted posts, including [auto-deleted old low-score questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year), all of which are only visible to moderators.

### ¿Es el bloqueo de preguntar o de responder la misma cosa que una suspensión?

No, a suspension is a manual, [temporary penalty](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) during which a user cannot ask questions, nor post answers. All other privileges, including commenting and voting, are also revoked by temporarily setting the reputation to 1. Such suspension is publicly visible to other users.

A post ban is enforced automatically, and only prevents posting questions or answers. It is invisible to others.

### ¿Cómo evito que se me bloquee para preguntar o responder?

[Read the pages in the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), particularly those [about asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and [the Stack Exchange model](https://stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange). Investigate and search before you ask. Put some effort in your questions.

All questions are expected to have some value for later visitors too. So if *many* of your questions do not get any answer, are downvoted, closed, or deleted by yourself or the community, then apparently they did not meet the required quality. Be sure to understand why that happens, and learn from that. Don't simply repost the same question again.

If you're not sure what qualifies as a "good question", there are some hints and tips available:

- [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) from the Stack Overflow Help Center
- [Writing the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) by Jon Skeet
- [How to Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) by Eric S. Raymond
- [Getting Answers](http://www.mikeash.com/getting_answers.html) by Mike Ash

To learn about formatting:

- [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)
- [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)
- Try for yourself in [the formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

### ¿Cuánto tiempo tengo que esperar para volver a publicar? ¿Qué puedo hacer para dejar de estar bloqueado? ¿Cómo puedo reactivar mi cuenta?

Automatic bans never expire or "time out." This means that you cannot simply wait for a certain amount of time. If you do not take action, you will never be allowed to post again. **The only way for the ban to be lifted is by contributing positively to the site in other ways**.

Moderators cannot lift the ban.

**Before you do anything else, *fix your existing posts!*** As noted above, down-votes cast by the rest of the community factor into the ban - so the single best thing you can do to get it lifted is to address any objections raised by others. Were your past questions unclear? Did they fail to show any effort on your part? Poorly worded, titled, formatted, and overly long or short? **Then fix them!**

Note the emphasis on fixing. **Do not delete your posts.** As explained above, deleted questions (if less than 30 days old when deleted) do still count towards the question ban. Deleting your posts does not help to lift the ban. Only fixing does! Under some conditions [you can see a list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13193/how-do-i-find-questions-or-answers-that-ive-deleted/13203#13203) of your own deleted questions and answers.

If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to ask *one* new one 6 months after your last question. If that question is positively received, you may be able to continue asking questions; if not, then the ban will be reinstated.

If you are banned from asking questions, then writing a few quality answers that get upvoted [might](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68884/why-i-cant-ask-questions/68885#68885) enable you to ask questions again. But as the internals of the filter are secret, there is no way to know for sure.

If you really, *really* think the ban is an error, then email the team directly using the "contact us" link provided at the bottom of every page. But note that reactivation of banned accounts [is not a high priority](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62373/better-explanation-when-account-is-blocked/62374#62374).

### ¿Puedo simplemente crear una nueva cuenta?

No. The automatic ban is at [a lower level than account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72180/clarify-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account-error/76167#comment-174366).

### ¡Lo preguntaré en otro sitio y desde allí migrarán la pregunta a este sitio!

Migrations are [not possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102293/block-migration-if-user-is-suspended-question-blocked-at-destination) if your account is banned from asking questions on the destination site. The question will simply be closed as off topic, but not migrated.

### ¿Aplica el bloqueo también a Meta?

Yes, but the threshold of votes in the auto ban calculation [is reduced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123068/152859) because downvotes can be more common on meta.

### ¿Por qué se me bloquea de preguntar / responder si mi cuenta tiene un buen rendimiento?

The ban also takes in account the IP address. If you browse from a shared computer, or from a location that gives the same IP address to many end users, it's enough that another user who was banned or triggers the ban, will affect everyone else accessing from the same location.

To help rectify this, browse from a different location.

Comment: Bloques copiados, ahora solo falta traducirlo al inglés y, si se tiene paciencia, buscar los artículos correspondientes en castellano. Si alguien se pone con ello, que avise por aquí y así evitamos tener a más de un usuario traduciendo en paralelo.