# ¿Por qué no me deja añadir preguntas en StackOverflow?

Tags: soporte, preguntas, bloqueo-de-publicación

Cuándo pulso en "Formular pregunta", no me deja añadir ninguna pregunta, solo me dice que he superado el límite. Dice que tengo muchas preguntas negativas pero la mayoría están en positivas. ¿Alguna solución?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Qué puedo hacer cuando recibo el comentario "Ya no aceptamos preguntas/respuestas de esta cuenta"?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4329/qu%c3%a9-puedo-hacer-cuando-recibo-el-comentario-ya-no-aceptamos-preguntas-respuest)

Comment: Usted probablemente tienen unas preguntas negativas eliminadas.

Comment: Tal vez hiciste muchas preguntas de baja calidad. ://

Comment: Revisando las preguntas que realizaste todas las eliminaste, pero me llama la atencion que todas tienen puntuacion negativa, seguramente requerian mas informacion o el formato no era adecuado, te sugiero revisar nuevamente [ask] que te brinda informacion para realizar preguntas en el sitio y estas sean bien recibidas.

Answer (score 3):

Te cito un fragmento del [Centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans):

> **¿Cómo puedo salir de la prohibición de preguntar?**
> La prohibición será levantada automáticamente por el sistema cuando determine que tus contribuciones positivas superan aquellas preguntas que fueron percibidas negativamente.

Pienso (realmente estoy seguro por que he visto tus preguntas), que tus preguntas fueron de muy mala calidad, no aportaban nada bueno al sitio. Por ese motivo se te prohibió realizar más preguntas.

Como dice el cuadro que te cité, debes de realizar otras contribuciones a la comunidad, para que se te elimine ese baneo. Siempre es aconsejable leer el [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), para tener claro como se deben de formular las preguntas, y evitar que te sucedan este tipo de cosas.

Saludos!

Comment: Lo he leído, y lo que tengo que hacer es corregir publicaciones negativas ¿no?

Comment: Por lo que entiendo tienes que limitarte a hacer comentarios y votar preguntas.

Comment: Añado, ya que la respuesta es correcta. Hiciste varias preguntas seguidas, parecidas, y de muy mala calidad. Las preguntas eliminadas CUENTAN para el limite de preguntas que el sistema toma en cuenta para saber si tus aportes son de calidad o no. Lo que tenes que hacer, es aceptar las respuestas que te sirvieron, o mejorar esas preguntas para recibir respuestas que sirvan. Tambien sirve que las respondas vos mismo. Y eliminar respuestas no va a levantar el baneo, repito las preguntas (eliminadas o no) cuentan para el baneo. @Programandosiempre